# LUA - is there a way to assign inputs from user to as keys for table?

Tags: input, lua

I'm a beginner in programming and i'd like to know if inputs from users can become keys for a table and how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

User input is related to "system programming" and is largely dependent on your platform. Lua doesn't have access to system-related stuff like input, graphics or audio so you need to use a library/framework for that. For example, love2d.org is a good Lua framework that can handle a lot of the system stuff. The following example checks the WASD keys only but you can easily expand that to check all the keys:

```
state = {}
keys = { "w", "a", "s", "d" }
function love.update(dt)
  for i, key in ipairs(keys) do
    local s = love.keyboard.isDown(key)
    if state[key] ~= s then
      state[key] = s
      if isdown then
        -- key press event
      else
        -- key release event
      end
    end
  end
end
```

An alternative could use callbacks:

```
state = {}
function love.keypressed(key)
  state[key] = true
end
function love.keyreleased(key)
  state[key] = false
end
```

Comment: Vanilla Lua does have I/O. It wouldn't really work as a stand-alone language without it. https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.8

Comment: True, I think I mentioned this in my answer. Your solution is good but it also assumes he has access to the console. I suspect he wants real-time input but it's impossible to tell from the question.

Comment: Just started love2d and I'd like to ask what math topics are essential to make a 2d game.

Comment: Hey Jason. Love2D is a great framework. Understanding vectors and a little bit of trigonometry can help you a lot. Nowadays there is a lot of information online so it's really more about knowing where to look for solutions. Also, check out my tutorials: https://2dengine.com/?p=tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`io.read`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-file:read) to get user input, and you can easily use that input as a table key. The following program is a very simplistic example that outputs its input.

```
local t = {
  [io.read()] = true,
}

-- next gets a key-value pair from t. The extra parentheses are to avoid
-- printing 'true' along with the key.
print((next(t)))
```